# Magento 1.9 How to install slick and make a slideshow

Tags: magento-1.9, slideshow

I put the slick folder in magento/skin/frontend/rwd/theme/ and I don't know what else to do. Please help me make a slideshow. I put these lines in my local.xml and i want the slideshow to be on my homepage.

```
   <action method="addItem">
       <type>skin_css</type>
       <item>slick/slick.css</item>
   </action>
   <action method="addItem">
       <type>skin_css</type>
       <item>slick/slick-theme.css</item>
   </action>
   <!-- add jquery if not present -->
   <action method="addItem">
       <type>skin_js</type>
       <item>slick/slick.min.js.css</item>
   </action>
```

Comment: Please, we need some more info, where do you want to put the slideshow for example, on the homepage, on the product page?

Comment: I want to put the slideshow on my homepage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you have posted should be in your `local.xml` file in the theme you are using (i assume you are using a child theme from RWD). This is going to make a call to the `skin/frontend/RWD/{theme}/` folders. The `skin_css` will make the call to the `css` folder in there, same for the `skin_js`. 
So now you need to get the slick files and put them in these places. So in example you would have a file:

> skin/frontend/rwd/{theme}/css/slick/slick.min.js

Once you have these files in place, you just need to use the slick api on the elements you want to have in the slider. So in the case of the homepage, you can place this code in the CMS page. In a default RWD install, you can do this in the admin `CMS->Pages->Home` with this code:

```
<div class="your-class">
  <div>your content</div>
  <div>your content</div>
  <div>your content</div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('.your-class').slick({
      infinite: true,
      slidesToShow: 3,
      slidesToScroll: 3
    });
  });
</script>
```

In this case, you need to make sure that you have jQuery set up correctly (that's another issue all together) but once you do, this should work for you.